# How can I maximize the root panel size in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, gwt-ext

How can I maximize the root panel size in GWT?

Answer (score 2):

For a full-window app, get your container with [RootPanel.get()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#get%28%29) or [RootLayoutPanel.get()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootLayoutPanel.html#get%28%29) in the EntryPoint's `onModuleLoad()`. Both will be attached to the document body as an absolutely positioned widget.

From the Mail sample:

```
public void onModuleLoad()
{
    DockLayoutPanel outer = binder.createAndBindUi(this);

    // Get rid of scrollbars, and clear out the window's built-in margin,
    // because we want to take advantage of the entire client area.
    Window.enableScrolling(false);
    Window.setMargin("0px");

    RootLayoutPanel root = RootLayoutPanel.get();
    root.add(outer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a div in your Project.html file with required dimensions. Than in your onModuoleLoad() method where you are using RootPanel use RootPanel.get('divID') i.e. (div created in html file). And thus you can have root panel of specified size.

Comment: RootPanel.get('divID'); giving error at ('divID') ...and this procedure will increase the size at design time to aad the widgets

Comment: @Monica 'divID' is the id of the div element that is already created in the html file.

Comment: I think there should not be any error. Or may be your id is wrong.

Comment: <div id="root" style="width: 1200px; margin: auto;"> in html file and at onModuoleLoad() i give  RootPanel.get('root'); but it give error at RootPanel.get('root'); portion ,is it give root to "root" instead of 'root' at on moduleLoad

Comment: I don't get an error, but this method isn't working for me either.

Answer (score 1):

Non-issue; the root panel is an absolute panel, and covers the entire browser real-estate